# Find text length minus the escape characters

Tags: android, string, string-length

How can I find the length of a string without counting certain escape characters? I'm looking for a method other than checking by myself each character one at a time... what functions other than .length() are available? I'm trying to output the character count of an entry, but when I type return it adds a character

Answer (score 2):

use string .replace, or .replaceall to replace your escape characters with an empty string "", then use the length ?

`String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`
Copies this string replacing occurrences of the specified target sequence with another sequence.

`String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)`
Copies this string replacing occurrences of the specified character with another character.

`String replaceAll(String regularExpression, String replacement)`
Replaces all matches for regularExpression within this string with the given replacement.

Taken from 
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

```
int count1 = StringUtils.countMatches("your_string", "your escape char1");
int count2 = StringUtils.countMatches("your_string", "your escape char2");
int count3 = StringUtils.countMatches("your_string", "your escape char3");
int count4 = StringUtils.countMatches("your_string", "your escape char4");
...

result = your_string_lenght - (count1 + count2 + count3 + count4);
```

It is not completely java or android. I think pseudo is clear.